# Why doesn't my boolean variable get set to True?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list **mem** that represents memory. **"-"** character represents empty space in it.
**memAlloc** function needs to find space if available (fragmented memory taken into account) and fill it with **data** value in **randSize** number of memory spaces.

```
def memAlloc(mem, data):
    randSize = randint(1, len(mem)//4)
    writeStart = 0
    writeSize = 0
    found = False

    for i in range(len(mem)):
        if(mem[i] == "-"):
            writeStart = i
            writeSize = 0
            for j in range(i, len(mem)):
                if(mem[j] == "-"):
                    writeSize += 1
                if(writeSize == randSize):
                    found = True
                    break
                else:
                    break
        if(found):
            break

    if(found):
        i = writeStart
        for j in range(writeSize):
            mem[i] = data
            i += 1
    else:
        print("Error: Not Enough Memory Space!")

    return mem
```

I really can't find the reason why there isn't enough space in memory. 
It seems that variable **found**, which indicates that available space is found, is never set True.
This is the output:
[image]

Comment: Why `else: break`?

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`  <--- Insert that just before your `for` loop with the `i` variable.  use `n` to hit each step and see where it fails.

Comment: Dear god... Thank you, user2357112.

Comment: Ignore mine.  @user2357112 nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would be clearer with less explicit index wrangling. You are just looking for a single slice of `mem` equal to some string like `"-----"` whose
length is determined by `randSize`.

(I'm making the assumption that `mem` is a list, and can thus be mutated by assigning to a slice. If `mem` is a string, some changes would be needed. If `mem` is something else altogether, some other changes might be necessary.)

```
class MemoryAllocationError(Exception):
    pass

def memAlloc(mem, data):
    randSize = randint(1, len(mem)//4)

    data = [data] * randSize  # Assuming data is a single character

    slot = ["-"] * randSize

    for i in range(len(mem) - randSize):
        if mem[i:i+randSize] == slot:
            break
    else:
        raise MemoryAllocationError("Not enough memory space")

    mem[i:i+randSize] = data

    return mem
```